# Play Framework 2.2.0 - Force the language using Filter and Global object

Tags: scala, localization, playframework-2.2

I've been trying to force the locale into the Request object depending on the host name of the application. This is done by reading a configuration Map

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.i18n.Lang
import play.api.Play.current
import scala.actors.Future

object Global extends WithFilters(ForceLocalization)

object ForceLocalization extends Filter {

  override def apply(next: (RequestHeader) => Future[SimpleResult])
                    (rh: RequestHeader): Future[SimpleResult] = {
    val arr = models.DomainSettings.forDomain(rh.domain).locale.split("_") // -> "en_US"
    val language = arr(0) // -> "en"
    val country = if ( arr.length == 1 ) "" else arr(1) // -> "US"
    f(rh).map( _.withLang(Lang(language, country)) ) 
  }

}
```

The code doesn't compile. It says:

```
type mismatch:
  [error]  found   : play.api.mvc.PlainResult
  [error]  required: play.api.mvc.SimpleResult
  [error]     f(rh).map( _.withLang(Lang(language, country)) )
```

Any suggestion?

Notice: I might probably have used a bad approach to achieve my goal, so if you have something better to suggest, I'll be glad to have your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm - seems like you've hit a bug related to Play's transitioning from `PlainResult` to `SimpleResult`.

When I look in  the **2.2.0** codebase, `PlainResult` is:

```
sealed trait PlainResult extends Result with WithHeaders[PlainResult]
```

and `SimpleResult` is defined as:

```
case class SimpleResult(...) extends PlainResult
```

... which means that all of the `WithHeaders` methods will be returning `PlainResult`s - which is wrong.

I note that in the [2.2.x codebase on GitHub](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.2.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Results.scala), it's been rectified:

```
case class SimpleResult(...) extends PlainResult with WithHeaders[SimpleResult]
```

... and if you're happy to use a Release Candidate, you can use **2.2.2-RC1** that contains the fix, according to the [release notes](http://www.playframework.com/changelog).

If not, employ a helper method to work around the problem, by doing what `WithHeaders.withLang` does anyway:

```
object ForceLocalization extends Filter {

  override def apply(next: (RequestHeader) => Future[SimpleResult])
                    (rh: RequestHeader): Future[SimpleResult] = {
    ...
    next(rh).map( withLang(_, Lang(language, country)) )
  }

  private def withLang(sr:SimpleResult, lang:Lang) = {
    sr.withCookies(Cookie(Play.langCookieName, lang.code))
  }
}
```